# Issue reading Excel file using Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, excel, kotlin, xlsx

I am going through my first experience writing an app using Kotlin and Android Studio. Whereas most things worked well or I was able to troubleshoot them (including writing an Excel file) I am not stuck for more than one day on trying to read data from an Excel file. I can compile the program but the app crashes when I try to run the part of the code linked to reading from Excel and more particularly the line using Workbookfactory. Here's the part of the code that gives an issue (print statements are just to allow me to see where the issue is) :

```
            println("Exceloutput function was called")
            val input = FileInputStream("/sdcard/Documents/test.xlsx")
            println("Exceloutput function did not crash")
            var xlwb = WorkbookFactory.create(input)
            println("Exceloutput function did not crash 2")
            val xlws = xlwb.getSheetAt(0)
            println("Exceloutput function did not crash 3")
            xlws.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("5")
            println("Exceloutput function did not crash 4")
            xlwb.close()
```

the libraries I've imported :

```
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.os.Environment
  import android.widget.*
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
  import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory
  import java.io.File
  import java.io.FileInputStream
  import java.io.FileOutputStream
  import java.io.FileWriter
  import java.net.URI.create
```

The dependencies I defined in build.gradle :

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2")
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2")
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.2")
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.2")
implementation("org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.0.3")
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Error messages I get when the app crashes :

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.preflightchecklisy, PID: 16159
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: error: The 'namespace-prefix' feature is not supported while the 'namespaces' feature is enabled.
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:68)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:259)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:118)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:98)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:224)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.create(Unknown Source:2)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:329)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-16$lambda-15$lambda-14$lambda-13$lambda-12$lambda-11$lambda-10$lambda-8(MainActivity.kt:193)
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$F-lh3xaeu6esj9SclhWcMZd_Rz4(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.onClick(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30213)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error: The 'namespace-prefix' feature is not supported while the 'namespaces' feature is enabled.
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.readFrom(ThemesTable.java:121)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.(ThemesTable.java:87)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRelation$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17.init(Unknown Source:2)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661) 
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:259) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:118) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:98) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:224) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.create(Unknown Source:2) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:329) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-16$lambda-15$lambda-14$lambda-13$lambda-12$lambda-11$lambda-10$lambda-8(MainActivity.kt:193) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$F-lh3xaeu6esj9SclhWcMZd_Rz4(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.onClick(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792) 
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769) 
at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30213) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: The 'namespace-prefix' feature is not supported while the 'namespaces' feature is enabled.
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:2550)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.lambda$parseToXmlObject$3(Locale.java:715)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.parse(Unknown Source:6)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.syncWrap(Locale.java:488)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:714)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:233)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.AbstractDocumentFactory.parse(AbstractDocumentFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.readFrom(ThemesTable.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.(ThemesTable.java:87) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRelation$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17.init(Unknown Source:2) 
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61) 
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661) 
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:259) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:118) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:98) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:224) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.create(Unknown Source:2) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:329) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-16$lambda-15$lambda-14$lambda-13$lambda-12$lambda-11$lambda-10$lambda-8(MainActivity.kt:193) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$F-lh3xaeu6esj9SclhWcMZd_Rz4(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.onClick(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792) 
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769) 
at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30213) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: The 'namespace-prefix' feature is not supported while the 'namespaces' feature is enabled.
at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:266)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:2523)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.lambda$parseToXmlObject$3(Locale.java:715) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.parse(Unknown Source:6) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.syncWrap(Locale.java:488) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:714) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:233) 
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.AbstractDocumentFactory.parse(AbstractDocumentFactory.java:71) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.readFrom(ThemesTable.java:119) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.(ThemesTable.java:87) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRelation$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17.init(Unknown Source:2) 
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61) 
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661) 
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:259) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:118) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:98) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:224) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.create(Unknown Source:2) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:329) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-16$lambda-15$lambda-14$lambda-13$lambda-12$lambda-11$lambda-10$lambda-8(MainActivity.kt:193) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$F-lh3xaeu6esj9SclhWcMZd_Rz4(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.example.PreFlightChecklist.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.onClick(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792) 
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769) 
at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30213) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

Quite impossible for me to figure that out since I am not an expert at all, more a newcomer to app programming. I tried searching on Internet but couldn't find the solution so would appreciate some expert help. Thanks in advance !